# How to make Vue Router Guards wait for Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

So all answers I've found publicly to this question weren't very helpful and while they "worked", they were incredibly hacky.

Basically I have a vuex variable, `appLoading` which is initially true but gets set to false once all async operations are complete. I also have another vuex variable called `user` which contains user information that gets dispatched from the async operation once it gets returned.

I then also have a router guard that checks;

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.getUser) {
      return next();
    }
    return router.push({ name: 'index.signup' });
  }

  return next();
});
```

In my initial Vue instance I then display a loading state until `appLoading = false;`

Now this "works" but there is a problem which is really bugging me. If you load the page, you will get a "flicker" of the opposite page you are supposed to see.

So if you are logged in, on first load you will see a flicker of the signup page. If you aren't logged in, you will see a flicker of the logged in page.

This is pretty annoying and I narrowed the problem down to my auth guard.
Seems it's pushing the signup page to the router since `user` doesn't exist then instantly pushes to the logged in page since `user` gets committed.

How can I work around this in a way that isn't hacky since it's kinda annoying and it's sort of frustrating that Vue doesn't have even the slightest bit of official docs/examples for a problem as common as this, especially since such a large number of webapps use authentication.

Hopefully someone can provide some help. :)

Comment: your `appLoading` should be a `promise` actually, which you can `await` in your hooks

Comment: @pranavjindal999 By default is it like this? And is it the actual state itself that's a promise, or the getter? Assuming it's the getter, can I just wrap my router guard in an if statement like; `if (store.getters.appLoading) { guard... } ?

Comment: It's upto you if you want to access it using getter or state directly. But the way you described it won't work. Hooks won't know when your state changed.
You have to make it the promise and `then` the entire hook into that promise.

Comment: @pranavjindal999 Not sure I follow. I think I get the general idea but is it possible you could give a small example? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The router beforeEach hook can be a promise and await for a Vuex action to finish. Something like:

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    await store.dispatch('init');

    if (store.getters.getUser) {
      return next();
    }
    return router.push({ name: 'index.signup' });
  }

  return next();
});
```

The 'init' action should return a promise:

```
const actions = {
  async init({commit}) {
    const user = await service.getUser();
    commit('setUser', user);
  }
}
```

This approach has the problem that whenever we navigate to a given page it will trigger the 'init' action which will fetch the user from the server. We only want to fetch the user in case we don't have it, so we can update the store check if it has the user and fetch it acordingly:

```
const state = {
  user: null
}
const actions = {
  async init({commit, state}) {
    if(!state.user) {
      const user = await service.getUser();
      commit('setUser', user);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion in comments:

Best approach for you case will be if you make your `appLoading` variable a `promise`. That's how you can do things or wait for things until your app data is resolved.

Considering `appLoading` a promise which you initialize with your api call promise, your router hook will be like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  appLoading.then(() => {
    if (to.matched.some(route => route.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      if (store.getters.getUser) {
        return next();
      }
      return router.push({ name: "index.signup" });
    }

    return next();
  });
});
```

You might want to just keep it as an export from your `init` code instead of keeping it in Vuex. Vuex is meant for reactive data that is shared over components.

Comment: Hey,
So something like this would work?
`export const init = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (store.getters.appIsLoading === false) {
    resolve();
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});`

Comment: I was hoping you could possibly give a bit more information on the promise wrapping part. I've tried a number of different ways with no luck. :/

Comment: You understanding of promises seems lacking. I'd suggest you to revisit promises. 
Good resource: http://javascript.info/async

Comment: The problem with this is the `router.beforeEach` hook executes before the store actions. The answer to the question is to call the action from inside this hook , based on the value of the `appLoading` state in the store. If it's undefined, call the action, if it's true, watch the store and if it's false, the state you want is already committed. You'll need to use async/await or `Promise.then()`